# scikit-learn grid search on multi-processor environment

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, scikit-learn

I am able to run the scikit-learn function GridSearchCV in parallel locally on my quad-core processor. I was wondering if it is straightforward to scale this to multi-processor environments using some module for MPI such as mpi4py.

I'm very new to this, so I would appreciate any extra relevant information too. I'm going through the documentation for mpi4py right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the [GridSearchCV implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/grid_search.py) as an inspiration to implement your own variant on top of MPI. However MPI might not offer a natural way to avoid transfering the input training set data over the network over and over.

An alternative would be to use [IPython.parallel](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/) as explained in this [tutorial](https://github.com/ogrisel/parallel_ml_tutorial). The code of the pyrallel helper lib used in this tutorial is also [available on github](https://github.com/pydata/pyrallel).

Answer (score 2):

I extended GridSearchCV to work with MPI, have a look at http://k-d-w.org/node/95

Currently, it only works with supervised learning algorithms, but modifications for unsupervised should be easy. Hope this helps.